# Override default password nag in Wordpress

Tags: functions, password, core

For some reason my default password nag is playing up on a big multi-user site I've setup. Pretty sure it's got to do with the [New User Approve](http://picklewagon.com/wordpress/new-user-approve/) and [Gravity Forms User Rego](http://www.gravityforms.com/add-ons/user-registration/) combo that I'm using.

Anyway, problem is I need to hack the core WP code every time I upgrade. The wp-admin/includes/user.php file has the 'default password nag' function... so I just change this to the wording I want. But of course it doesn't stick and needs to be done every upgrade! Big hassle.

```
add_action('admin_notices', 'default_password_nag');
function default_password_nag() {
global $pagenow;
if ( 'profile.php' == $pagenow || ! get_user_option('default_password_nag') ) 
    return;

echo '<div class="error default-password-nag">';
echo '<p>';
echo '<strong>' . __('Notice:') . '</strong> ';
_e('You&rsquo;re using the auto-generated password for your account. Would you like to change it to something easier to remember?');
echo '</p><p>';
printf( '<a href="%s">' . __('Yes, take me to my profile page') . '</a> | ', get_edit_profile_url( get_current_user_id() ) . '#password' );
printf( '<a href="%s" id="default-password-nag-no">' . __('No thanks, do not remind me again') . '</a>', '?default_password_nag=0' );
echo '</p></div>';
}
```

Each time I change it to this, which works a treat:

```
add_action('admin_notices', 'default_password_nag');

function default_password_nag() {
global $pagenow;
if ( 'profile.php' == $pagenow || ! get_user_option('default_password_nag') ) 
    return;

echo '<div class="error default-password-nag">';
echo '<p>Visit your ';
printf( '<a href="%s">' . __('profile page') . '</a> to update your password any time. ', admin_url('profile.php') . '#password' );
echo '</p></div>';
   }
```

But I want a permanent fix. Any advice will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Great. Using @s_ha_dum action in the right way (in functions.php). Full code is:

```
add_action('admin_notices', 'aa99_delete_pass_nag', 1);
function aa99_delete_pass_nag() {
remove_action('admin_notices','default_password_nag');
}

function aa99_add_password_nag() {
global $pagenow;
if ( 'profile.php' == $pagenow || ! get_user_option('default_password_nag') ) 
    return;

echo '<div class="error default-password-nag">';
echo '<p>Visit your ';
printf( '<a href="%s">' . __('profile page') . '</a> to update your password at any time. ', admin_url('profile.php') . '#password' );
echo '</p></div>';
}
add_action('admin_notices', 'aa99_add_password_nag');
```

Answer (score 0):

The function is hooked to an action, so you should be able to remove it.

```
remove_action('admin_notices','default_password_nag');
```

You can then add back a function of your own choosing. Rename your function to something that won't conflict with the Core function name and...

```
add_action('admin_notices','my_password_nag');
```

You will need to create a plugin or mu-plugin to do it, but those are relatively easy to create.

Comment: Looks good, but are you saying I can't use this in functions.php?

Comment: It should probably work in the theme's `functions.php` but if it isn't a theme you've written that will be overwritten when the theme updates.

Comment: Thanks. Pretty much all my themes are ones that I've made myself ;-)